# MongoDB copyDatabase failed with dbOwner

Tags: mongodb

I have a remote mongo database in which I've setup a certain data base and a user with a dbOwner privileges.
I can access to this db with this user info, but I can not copy this data using copyDatabase.
I've read that a **find** access is required, but isn't that part of an owner access?
it's specifically mentioned in the documentation (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/) that owner has all the admin rights, and admin has the find right.
but, when trying to call this function, I'm getting

> "errmsg" : "exception: nextSafe(): { $err: \"not authorized for query on db1.system.users\",

For a reference, here is what getUser returns:

> > db.getUser('mu1')
> >
> > {
> >         "_id" : "db1.mu1",
> >         "user" : "mu1",
> >         "db" : "db1",
> >         "roles" : [
> >             {
> >                 "role" : "dbOwner",
> >                 "db" : "db1"
> >             }
> >         ]
> >     }

How can this happen to an owner of db1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are access requirements on both the source and target databases in order to be able to perform a copy.  Assuming you are using 2.6 (which I think you are given that the dbOwner role was introduced in 2.6), the requirements are laid out in detail here (note: you should not use copyDatabase [with roles in 2.4](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/command/copydb/#authentication)):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/#required-access

The copy actually runs on the target instance (the one you are copying to), so I'm guessing that is the issue here, that you do not have the [correct permissions on the target](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/#target-database-todb) host.

Comment: Hey and thanks for your response!
the target is my local db that contains no authentication (auth is off), and I'm still getting this error.
The DB version is 2.6x

Comment: Also, cancelling the auth on the remote db enables me to copy with ease.

Comment: Hmmm, since this is not an admin DB you shouldn't need access to `system.users` and dbOwner should be more than enough.  That makes me wonder if the authentication is succeeding and granting you that role for the copyDatabase.  It will take me a little while to get some testing set up.  If you wanted to do a little differential diagnosis yourself in the meantime, you could try using the `root` role for that user temporarily and see if it still fails.  If it does, then that would imply that the issue is getting authenticated as the user rather than the role the user has (root has all access)

Comment: I'll try the root idea, but I do have read/write access with that user, I am able to create/delete/get records. I'll let you know about the root thing

Comment: When root, copyDatabase works fine. 
So I do need some system access. I enabled system.readWrite - did nothing. it says db1.system.users. can't make how to enable this.
thanks for all the help and the time you already spent

Comment: Try: `{ resource: { db: "db1", collection: "system.users" }, actions: [ "find" ] }` and then add insert to the actions if it still fails.

Comment: I saw that in the documentation, when I run it, I get:  Unexpected token :.
I probably run it in the wrong place?

Comment: So it seems that the db.system.users is from an older version, and it's bulletproof (can't delete this event with root privilege). however, I can empty it -  and even for that root wouldn't work - have to restart with no auth to clear this db. lets see if this will take.

Comment: still getting this error when trying to copy. The fact that this thing can not be deleted while not in use by the new version is a bug.

Comment: Did you do this when you upgraded? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade-authorization/ There is a process to upgrade the user auth data when you go to 2.6 - if you did this and the issue is still there, then it's probably a (reproducible) bug, but if not then that is likely the root cause here.

Comment: Run that, got the ok, copyDatabase still fails, same error as before.

Comment: My bad - it even tells you that the data remains intact at the end of that page.  Seems that is the issue, so need to figure out a way to get rid of that permanently (assuming no issues post-migration)

Comment: any solution for this issue out there ?

Comment: Well I ended up giving dbOwner role on the database I want to copy and the root role on the db admin to my user.